# unit testing - stubbing or mocking finagle client

Tags: unit-testing, finagle, twitter-finagle

Here is the few lines of code I would like to unit test for different http response codes. One of them is code 201 . Please advise

```
val cb = ClientBuilder()
val myClient = cb.build()
val req =
      RequestBuilder()
        .url(loginUrl)
        .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .buildPost(copiedBuffer(body.getBytes(UTF_8)))

myClient(req).map(http.Response(_)).flatMap { response =>
      response.statusCode match {
        case 201 => //parse response
        case _ =>
          println(" some reseponse")
          Future(proxy(response))
       }
}
```

Comment: If you encapsulate the `201` logic into a method, at least you could trivially verify it through a unittest

Comment: @dm03514  I am sure it could be done something along these lines but could not get it to work . 
   `
    val request = Request()
    val service = mock[Service[http.Request, http.Response]]
     stub(service(any[http.Request])).toReturn(Future.value(Response(request.version, http.Status.Created)))
    stub(service.close()).toReturn(Future.Done)`